# Converting a upper case database to proper case

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL and I have several large database with upper case first and last names that I need to convert to proper case in SQL sever 2008.

I am using the following to do this:

```
update database 
Set FirstNames = upper(substring(FirstNames, 1, 1))
                     + lower(substring(FirstNames, 2, (len(FirstNames) - 1) ))
```

I was wondering if there was any way to adapt this so that a field with two first names is also updated (currently I make the change and then go through and manually change the second name).

I have looked over the other answers in this field and they all seem quit long, compared to the query above.

Also is there any way to assist with converting the Mc suranmes ( I will manually change the others)? MCDONALD to McDonald, again I am just using the about query but replacing the FirstNames with LastName.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably best done outside of SQL.  However, if there is a requirement to do it on the server or if speed isn't an issue (because it will be an issue so you need to figure out if you care), the way you are going about it is probably the best way of doing so.  If you want, you could create a UDF that puts all of the logic in one area.

Here is some code I came across (with attribution and more information below it):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fCapFirst(@input NVARCHAR(4000)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @position INT
WHILE IsNull(@position,Len(@input)) > 1
SELECT @input = Stuff(@input,IsNull(@position,1),1,upper(substring(@input,IsNull(@position,1),1))), 
@position = charindex(' ',@input,IsNull(@position,1)) + 1
RETURN (@input)
END

--Call it like so
select dbo.fCapFirst(Lower(Column)) From MyTable
```

I got this code from http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=37760  There is more information and other suggestions in this forum as well.

As for dealing with cases like the McDonald, I would suggest one of two ways to handle this.  One would be to put a search in the above UDF for key names ('McDonald', 'McGrew', etc.) or for patterns (the first two letters are Mc then make the next one capital, etc.)  The second way would be to put these cases (the full names) in a table and have their replacement value in a second column.  Then simply do a replace.  Most likely, however, it will be easiest to identify rules like Mc then capitalize instead of trying to list every last-name possibility.

Don't forget you may want to modify the above UDF to include dashes, not just spaces.

Comment: Thanks, just one more question - you mention modifing the UDF to include dashes. To do this, would it just be changing/adding to the '@position = charindex(' ',@input,IsNull(@position,1)) + 1 ' part? What change is needed? Sorry, very new to SQL...

Comment: @Dianne - Yes, basically you would do the loop twice.  Once for the spaces (the line you identified) and again a second time for the dashes.  Another way to do it would be to find the position of the next space or dash.  That would be more complex but it would allow you to do the loop only once.

Comment: @Dianne: You could replace `charindex(' ',@input,IsNull(@position,1))` with `patindex('%[ -]%',@input,IsNull(@position,1))`. The `%[ -]%` pattern can also be extended to include other characters, if needed.

Comment: I used your function but when updating the fields some of them were blank, where they used to have a field?   
update Employee 
Set lastName = dbo.fCapFirst(Lower(lastname))

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is too long but it is very easy and can be adapted for `-`, `'`, etc:

```
UPDATE tbl SET LastName = Case when (CharIndex(' ',lastname,1)<>0) then (Upper(Substring(lastname,1,1))+Lower(Substring(lastname,2,CharIndex(' ',lastname,1)-1)))+ 
 (Upper(Substring(lastname,CharIndex(' ',lastname,1)+1,1))+
 Lower(Substring(lastname,CharIndex(' ',lastname,1)+2,Len(lastname)-(CharIndex(' ',lastname,1)-1)))) 
  else (Upper(Substring(lastname,1,1))+Lower(Substring(lastname,2,Len(lastname)-1))) end, 
FirstName = Case when (CharIndex(' ',firstname,1)<>0) then (Upper(Substring(firstname,1,1))+Lower(Substring(firstname,2,CharIndex(' ',firstname,1)-1)))+ 
 (Upper(Substring(firstname,CharIndex(' ',firstname,1)+1,1))+
 Lower(Substring(firstname,CharIndex(' ',firstname,1)+2,Len(firstname)-(CharIndex(' ',firstname,1)-1)))) 
  else (Upper(Substring(firstname,1,1))+Lower(Substring(firstname,2,Len(firstname)-1))) end;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tony Rogerson](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx) has code that deals with:

- double barrelled names eg Arthur Bentley-Smythe
- Control characters

I haven't used it myself though...